# Magento site wont load after reindexing crashed

Tags: magento-1.9

My magento website wont load the admin or front end. I updated a new category with some products and flushed the cache and done a reindex. But as I done it, chrome froze on me. Now it wont load anything.

It just shows a white screen.

Comment: Go to index.php remove comment from `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `index.php`. It will help you too understand what is the main problem

```
  ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
    register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
    function fatal_handler() {
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo("<pre>");
        print_r($error);
    }
```

Hope this will help you to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Ended up restarting nginx and it seemed to work